# jquery tabs selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

the jquery code is like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    $("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("active").show(); //Activate first tab
    $(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
```

and the tabs:

```
    <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        <!--Content-->
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
       <!--Content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

whenever the page loads the 1st tab is opened 1st. but if i want the 2nd tab to show, then how can i do that. like from inside a function 
im loading the page like: window.location="display.php";
when loaded i want the 2nd tab to open how to do that?? also from another function if i want the 1st tab to show how to do that?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do it like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //When page loads...
    $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
    var index = $("ul.tabs li.active").show().index(); 
    $(".tab_content").eq(index).show();

    //On Click Event
    $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {

        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        $(this).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content

        var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the href attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        return false;
    });

});
```

then on the tabs (`li`) on the html, set an active like,

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
        <!--Content-->
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
       <!--Content-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have a typo on setting the class on `li` above. when you want `tab2` set the `class="active"` on tab2 `li`. Not by javascript that is. for example, in `display.php`, `<li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Gallery</a></li>` and on another page, `<li class="active"><a href="#tab2">Submit</a></li>`

Comment: the same problem remailns.. tab1 is displayed everytime, isnt there any way while im leaving the page the active tab will remain active after reload??

Comment: Yup! the concept of setting the class active on different conditions worked.. thanxx a lot!!